# How to reference d.ts files from Nuget in VS2015?

Tags: asp.net, typescript, nuget, visual-studio-2015

In CTP6 I'm noticing that Nuget packages are getting pulled down to the %User%/.k/packages folder and then referenced in the app. This seems to be OK for DLL references, but if I'm trying to pull DefinitelyTyped packages from Nuget (because they don't all exist in NPM or Bower yet), how do I get these files back to my ASP.NET 5 project so I can reference the d.ts in my Typescript files? I could manually move them, but if I do that I'd probably not use Nuget and just download the files directly.

Comment: The Definitely Typed NuGet packages add the `.d.ts` files to `Scripts/...` usually - is this not happening?

Comment: Not in 2015. I think that is what happens in 2013 and earlier. Maybe this is just something not quite baked in the 2015 CTP.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet files should not contain static files anymore. This is the new direction. NuGet is basically a way to handle dependencies between assemblies. Including static files was a nice side effect back then.

With [asp.net-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-5), it becomes a problem. So they switched to [bower](/questions/tagged/bower) to handle those packages.

At the time of writing your question, there might have been some missing DefinitelyTyped packages on bower but it seems that they can be found with the `dt-` prefix.

Like so: http://bower.io/search/?q=dt-

So for the jQuery `d.ts` file, I would go with `dt-jquery` and... it happens to be right there.